# Not able to store the value of 2nd drop down in servlet using request.getParameter

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, postgresql, servlets

I have 2 dropdowns. The 2nd dropdown is populated according to what I select on the first. In my form 2nd drop down came automatically after select 1st one using ajax in java.But my problem is I can't store the value of 2nd drop down in servlet like 1st drop down using request.getParameter

Comment: Could you please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38540484/edit) to include the code you have problems with?

Comment: not clear about the question can you please copy paste the code

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get whatever selected in drop-down by request.getParameter()

```
String first = request.getParameter("first");

String second = request.getParameter("second");
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is, you can try
 **Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();**
to get all possible parameters from your form. Then iterate through among them to get your required values based on parameter names.